# The value "(string)" is invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-5

I currently have a view that contains two text boxes where users can enter in some data.  One text box only allows values of 1-10, the other a string.  I am not sure what code change I made, but the second text box accepting a string no longer "works".  For example, when I enter in a string and try to submit the form, I get a validation message that states "The value "(string)" is invalid.  Below are some code snippets in my solution.

Entity:

```
public class MovieReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10)]
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Review { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
    private MovieLoversDb _db = new MovieLoversDb();

    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int movieId)
    {
        var movie = _db.Movies.Find(movieId);
        if (movie != null)
        {
            return View(movie);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int movieId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MovieReview review)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.MovieReviews.Add(review);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = review.MovieId });
        }
        return View(review);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@model MovieLovers.Models.MovieReview

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Review a Movie";
}

<h2>Review a Movie</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>New Review</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Review)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Review)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Review)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewerName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewerName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewerName)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

The question now is, what am I doing wrong?  Why is that validation error generating?

Comment: I think you have posted another view. Your posted view is only display the list. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I apologize.  Updating now.

Comment: Do you have another field on the rendered page named `Review`?

Comment: Nope.  The original page and the partial, there's only one field named Review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out using a suggestion by Jasen in comments under the original post.  It seems as though "Review" may have been used twice, although I could not find where.  I changed the property name to "body" and now it works.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The two times are the property "MovieReview.Review" and the action parameter "(MovieReview review)".

Answer (score 3):

the problem is the name of the field is review:

> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Review)

as the name of the parameter in the control:

> public ActionResult Create(MovieReview review)

Changing the name of the parameter should works too

Answer (score 1):

Please try using

```
public class MovieReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10)]
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string? Review { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can't.  I am using MovieReview in a generic type on another entity.  I get an error stating this field cannot be null.

Comment: You used EF. Right? And the approaching is model first?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because your domain class has property named Review (`public string Review { get; set; }`) and method that is receiving updated domain class has parameter named review also (`public ActionResult Create(MovieReview review)`).

Change `public ActionResult Create(MovieReview review)` to `public ActionResult Create(MovieReview movieReview)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in below model.Review and Model.Rating can't be directly accessible as your Mode is IEnumerable

```
     <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Review)
    </th>
```

Comment: I removed the "IEnumerable" and it still displays the validation message.  Same goes for the Edit action I recently created for this.

Answer (score 0):

your var name should not be same as a class name try this :

```
public class MovieReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10)]
    [Required]
    public int ratingId { get; set; }
    public string reviewText { get; set; }
    public int movieId1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`

or

remove all `ValidationMessageFor` and change for(remove true)  `@Html.ValidationSummary()`

Edit:

You want to be remove all `ValidationMessageFor` and change the `ValidationSummary(true)` to `ValidationSummary()`

Comment: Will this then remove validation on these forms, though?

Comment: You want to be remove all ValidationMessageFor and change the ValidationSummary(true) to ValidationSummary()